# How can you get a list of pull requests reviewed in a repository by a user from the GitHub API?

Tags: github-api

On the GitHub website, it is possible to list PRs reviewed by a user for a specific repository with the filter query `is:pr reviewed-by:your-github-username`. [See example.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ndnC1.png)

But I can't find how to replicate this functionality using the GitHub API. Is there a query you can make that will do something like `GET /repos/:owner/:repo/pulls/reviewedby/:reviewer`?

Answer (score 2):

The `search` endpoint turned out to be the key. Example request:
`https://api.github.com/search/issues?q=+type:pr+repo=facebook/react+reviewed-by:bvaughn`